# Azure LinearRetry - Parameter retryInterval must be declared as 'value' error

Tags: c#, azure, lambda, delegates

// This is what I declared

```
internal delegate Func<Func<int, Exception, TimeSpan, bool>> RetryPolicy();

public static RetryPolicy LinearRetry(int retryCount, TimeSpan intervalBetweenRetries)
        {
            return () =>
            {
                return (int currentRetryCount, Exception lastException, out TimeSpan retryInterval) =>
                {
                    // Do custom work here               
                    // Set backoff
                    retryInterval = intervalBetweenRetries;
                    // Decide if we should retry, return bool
                    return currentRetryCount < retryCount;

                };
            };
        }
```

This is [a linear retry mechanism implemented in Azure](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2011/02/03/overview-of-retry-policies-in-the-windows-azure-storage-client-library.aspx).

I don't understand this syntax. It is supposedly accepts void and returns a delegate that accepts 3 parameters and returning bool but I get this error I am getting Parameter retryInterval must be declared as 'value' error.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you have a mismatch between the delegate type and what you're actually returning. If you want to use `out`, you can't use `Func`, you need a custom delegate type. (And if I ignored the `out` issue, your code still wouldn't work, because there should be only one `Func`.)

Based on the article you linked to, the `RetryPolicy` delegate should return a `ShouldRetry` delegate, so I'm going to call it that. Using this, your code will compile:

```
public delegate bool ShouldRetry(int currentRetryCount, Exception lastException, out TimeSpan retryInterval);

public delegate ShouldRetry RetryPolicy();
```

---

Now, I said that the code will compile, but I didn't say that it will work. I couldn't find any official documentation about this `RetryPolicy` delegate type and also the article is pretty old. What I did find are a bunch of types in [the `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.RetryPolicies` namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.retrypolicies.aspx), including `IRetryPolicy`, which might be what you're actually looking for.